# How to remove window title bar completely?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, titlebar

So, in the past, I used to be able to make a simple call like the one below to make a window without a title bar on it or border around it:

```cpp
a = SetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, winstyle AND NOT WS_BORDER);
```

I just tried the exact same style code earlier today on Windows 11, and things aren't performing as they used to.

In the past, a window was created without *ANY* border or title bar.  Now, my program is creating a window with a BLACK/blank title bar.  There's nothing there to interact with, but the window is still reserving real estate for the blank title bar, with the program window appearing below it (which causes issues with automated mouse clicks across various computers on our system with different size title bars and borders).

Is this a new, permanent, type behavior which Windows 11 is implementing?  A glitch which will be fixed in some future update?  Or does anyone have a simple work-around for which I can fall back on until I can sort out why it USED to work but now doesn't?

Comment: Note `SetWindowLong` is not supported for 64bit applications, you'll need to use [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra) instead. In general I would also suggest using the Wide or "unicode" versions of any API from MS, the A or Ansi versions may not act as you expect.

Comment: This doesn't require Win11 to misbehave.  Changing the frame style requires an additional call to SetWindowPos() with the SWP_FRAMECHANGED style flag.

Comment: `AND NOT WS_BORDER` is not c, unless `NOT` is a macro for bitwise NOT `~`

Comment: @mge `SetWindowLong` is supported on 64-bit Windows and 64-bit applications. The `GWL_STYLE` index in particular fits into 32 bits of memory. There is no requirement to call `SetWindowLongPtr`.

Comment: @IInspectable please see the link in my comment `SetWindowLong` is **explictly** not supported on 64-bit platforms *"To write code that is compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, use SetWindowLongPtr. When compiling for 32-bit Windows, SetWindowLongPtr is defined as a call to the SetWindowLong function."*

Comment: @mge I'm familiar with the documentation. I fail to see how you read that `SetWindowLong` were not supported on 64-platforms into that, and most certainly fail to see that this were being made explicitly. `SetWindowLong` doesn't work for pointer-sized values on 64-bit architectures. The window style being set isn't pointer-sized.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally sorted out the issue.

```cpp
Style = (WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU); 
a = SetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, winstyle & ~WS_BORDER);
```

The issue was coming from simply removing the WS_CAPTION and not also removing the WS_SYSMENU flag, which ends up with the title bar becoming black and blank, but not non-existent.  I swear, in my memory, all I had to remove was the WS_CAPTION in the past (perhaps on 32-bit systems?), and it completely removed the title bar from a program, but things aren't behaving that way now.  Now it's a case of having to remove both WS_CAPTION and WS_SYSMENU flags to make that titlebar disappear completely.

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>